# Load custom DLLs with WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, webbrowser-control

Attempting to take screenshots of web pages 'headlessly' using a WebBrowser control. I realise this may not be the best course of action, but long story short, our company uses IE and we can only use IE to view certain browser-based applications. I believe the application loads certain DLLs/ActiveX controls that only work in IE. So I am trying to load pages that use these ActiveX controls in the WebBrowser control, take the screen shot, then return the image in whatever browser the user feels like using.

This approach works fine for 'www.google.com' (as it doesn't load any custom DLLs), but not for our web based app - I get a crash:

> The program '[4516] WebDev.WebServer40.EXE: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).

And the fault module name is the specific DLL that the web app requires. So the question is, how do I ensure the required DLLs are loaded with the WebBrowser control, as they would be when I open IE? Perhaps it is a permissions issue?

Comment: `WebDev` is Visual Studio's development server _"cassini"_. Have you tried running it in IIS, or IIS Express. (For IISExpress, right click your project and choose _Run in IIS Express_)

Comment: Hi gideon, changed to IISExpress but crashed, same Fault Module Name.